# How do I put multiple PHP commands in one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I put multiple php commands like:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

//get the user.id 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.email LIKE '$email'");
$user_id = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$user_id = $user_id["id"];

//fill the album -> "Profilbilder"

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `album` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES ('$user_id', 'Profilbilder')") or    die(mysql_error()); 

//get the album.id
$result = mysql_query("SELECT album.id FROM album WHERE album.user_id = '$user_id'");
$album_id = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$album_id = $album_id["id"];        


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `foto` (`album_id`, `name`, `zeitstempel`, `link`) VALUES ('$album_id',    '$file_name', NOW(), '$file_path')") or die(mysql_error());
```

---

.. to get database information in one big command?

Comment: Are you talking about making a transaction?

Comment: This is not a php question, it is about SQL. Take a look at the documentation of your sql server and learn about joins and subqueries.

Comment: `$album_id = mysql_insert_id();` may help.

Comment: I cant figure out his question either... Please reword and update.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually insert into a table the results from a query like so:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `album` 
           (`user_id`, `name`) 
           SELECT user.id, 'Profilbilder' 
           FROM `user` 
           WHERE user.email LIKE '%$email%'";
```

Comment: And you could get the album id and user id in one query if you wanted (look up sql joins).